# Node: Wait for python script to run

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have the following code. Where i upload the file first and then i read the file and `console` the output like `console.log(obj)`. But the response comes first and the python scripts runs behind the scene. **How can i make code to wait for the python script to run then proceed?**

```
router.post(`${basePath}/file`, (req, res) => {

    //Upload file first

    PythonShell.run('calculations.py', { scriptPath: '/Path/to/python/script' }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        let obj = fs.readFileSync('Path/to/file', 'utf8');
        console.log(obj);
    });

    return res.status(200).send({
        message : 'Success',
    });
});
```

I cannot get `console.log(obj);` output because it runs after the response. **How can i make it wait for the python script to run and get `console.log(obj)` output on console.**

Comment: Try to move `res.status(200).send` at the end of the third `PythonShell.run` argument callback's body.  This will send a 200-response after the script is done.

Comment: Do you want to respond script's running result on that POST request? And do you see the result of `console.log(obj)`  in the console output?

Comment: @dhilt No i cannot see the output of `console.log(obj)` in the console. And i want to return response as the output of `console.log(obj)`.

Comment: Okey, I've just tried to give an answer.

Comment: @Gammer could you tell be how you have send data from python script . I guess the problem is with script . I have tried this onces , what you have done in python to pass the data  to node ?

Comment: can you will able to add the python code how you print or pass the data . Last time i work on it you have to just print in python script that will we reflect on node.js console as you are doing .

Comment: @Himanshusharma Check the below answer comments please

Comment: from the code i can only see `let obj = fs.readFileSync('Path/to/file', 'utf8');` is not working , check for file is there is content or file , if there is no content then only this would be an error . Please debug that once .

Comment: @Himanshusharma the file is there, It have content the `let obj = fs.readFileSync('Path/to/file', 'utf8');` works outside of `PythonShell`. But not works inside

Comment: I tested you script working fine in my PC .

Comment: That's weird...

Answer (score 5):

To return the result after some async operation, you should call `res.send` inside the done-callback.

```
router.post(`${basePath}/file`, (req, res) => {

    //Upload file first

    PythonShell.run('calculations.py', { scriptPath: '/Path/to/python/script' }, function (err) {
        console.log('The script work has been finished.'); // (*)
        if(err) {
          res.status(500).send({
            error: err,
          });
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        let obj = fs.readFileSync('Path/to/file', 'utf8');
        console.log(obj); // (**)
        res.status(200).send({
            message : 'Success',
        });
    });
});
```

Then if you will not see the log (*) in the console, then it would mean that the script does not work or works improperly. The callback is not being called. First of all, you need to be sure that the script (PythonShell.run) works and the callback is being called. The POST handler will wait until you call `res.send` (with no matter of delay value), so that callback is the main point.

Also readFileSync could fail. In case of readFileSync failure you should see an exception. If it's ok then you'll see the next log (**) and the response will be sent.

---

I see `PythonShell` in your code. I have no experience with it, but after some reading I think that the problem could be in how you are using it. It seems the [`python-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) npm package, so following it's documentation you may try to to instantiate a python shell for your script and then to use listeners:

```
let pyshell = new PythonShell('calculations.py');

router.post(`${basePath}/file`, (req, res) => {
  pyshell.send(settings); // path, args etc
  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    console.log('The script work has been finished.');
    if(err) { res.status(200).send({ error: err }); }
    else { res.status(200).send({ message : 'Success' }); }
  });
});
```

This approach could be more appropriate because the pyton shell is kept open between different POST requests. This depends on your needs. But I guess it does not solve the problem of script running. If you are sure that the script itself is fine, then you need just to run it properly in the Node environment. There are some points:

- path to script
- arguments
- other settings

Try to remove all arguments (create some new test script), cleanup settings object (keep only path) and execute it from Node. Handle its result in Node. You should be able to run the simplest script by correct path! Research how to setup correct `scriptPath`. Then add an argument to your script and run it with an argument. Hanlde the result again. There are not so [many options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#pythonshellscript-options-constructor), but each of them could be the cause of improper call.

Comment: Great explanation, That make sense, But the above code is not returning response not showing any kind of message or output in the console.

Comment: After sending a request from the POSTMAN, with a file which is saving locally as expected etc, i haven't get anything except the route names after each call which is fine.

Comment: That means exactly that `PythonShell.run` does not work. I'm afraid I know nothing about such a script running,  this is out of my competence. You need to debug `PythonShell.run` call.

Comment: I also think so .

Comment: The script i am running with `PythonShell.run` is fine becasue with that script i am creating file which is creating and python part is working fine.  `fs.readFileSync` is to read the file which is there and works outside `PythonShell.run()` but do not work inside of it.

Comment: If the script itself is ok, then the issue is how the Node tries to run it. What is `PythonShell`? whst is `PythonShell.run`? I will try to update the answer after reading...